# Create table based on div - row's border

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I wolud like to create a table based on div. Here is my CSS code:

```
.div-table{
display:table;         
width: 100%;         
border: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
}

.div-table-row{
display:table-row;
width: 100%;
clear:both;
text-align: center;
}

.div-table-row-head{
display:table-row;
background: #33A1DE;
color: #fff;
width: 100%;
line-height: 280%;
clear:both;
}

.div-table-col-head{
float:left;
display: table-column;
min-height: 50px;
border-right: 1px solid #C9C9C9;  
border-top: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 17px;
border-top: none;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 15px;
}

.div-table-col{
float:left;
display: table-column;
min-height: 50px;
border-right: 1px solid #C9C9C9;  
border-top: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
}
```

And my HTML code:

```
<div class="div-table">
<div class="div-table-row-head">
    <div class="div-table-col-head">USTAWIENIA</div>
</div>
<div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 19.73%;">001 hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hh hh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hh hh hhh hhh hhh hhh</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">002</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">003</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">003</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%; border-right: none;">003</div>
</div>
<div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 19.73%;">xxx</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">yyy</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">www</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">www</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%; border-right: none;">www</div>
</div>
<div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 19.73%;">ttt</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">uuu</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">Mkkk</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%;">Mkkk</div>
    <div class="div-table-col" style="width: 20%; border-right: none;">Mkkk</div>
</div>
```

Here is output: http://jsbin.com/IkiqaSir

And how I can remove breaks into borders of rows? You can see it in first row.

Comment: If you're creating tabular data then why not use a <table>?

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `<table>`?

Comment: You know the div/table breaks when you downsize it right? The 5th row moves down.

Comment: Because I wolud like to create a options in this table in my admin panel. `<table>` using is not professional, you know :>

Comment: Use the `<table>` tag. Don't reinvent the wheel by trying to implement a table using `<div>s`

Comment: "`<table>` using is not professional". Same old mistake! Use tables for tabular *data*, use CSS for the page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<table>`

**[JSFiddle Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/5JP5s/)**

**[JSFiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/5JP5s/1/)** - an example with lots of content in one of the cells.

**CSS**

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; width:100%;}
table {border:1px solid #ccc;}
table th { border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; text-align: left; padding:10px; background:#33A1DE; color:#fff;}
table td { padding:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">content</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Fine but how I can delete `font-weight: bold` from head of table ? `font-weight: none;` is not helpufl for me.

Comment: @user3022527 `font-weight:none` is invalid, `none` can't be used, if you want to remove the bold, then set it to `font-weight:normal`